# How many controllers (services,factories,directives) in one AngularJS file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My AngularJS application is growing and we have over one hundred controllers, services and directives in one file.  Line count is approaching 25,000 and I'm wondering if I am approaching some limit (Angular, JavaScript or otherwise).  Am I?

Comment: Perhaps you should separate them out and group on based on something. It will be easier to maintain in the future. For example, you have to change something in one directive or service, instead of editing a massive file, you can just edit 1 small file, if you make a mistake it is much easier to track down

Comment: You could go on until your file limit exceeds the space on your server but for the sake of maintainability you should think about a project structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably isn't really a line limit, but I can imagine your file being insanely chaotic and almost unreadable. 
You should consider to split your 1 file in a couple of files, like 1 file for your controllers (or if you have clear groupings of controllers, separate the controllers in a few files aswell) and 1 file for your services etc. You can create new modules for the services and controllers and then inject those in your main module.

The huge advantage: your code is much easier to maintain and understand, and it is much easier to track down errors and bugs instead of having to scroll through 25k lines of code.

Also, should you for some reason pass the project on to someone else, he/she will be able to read your project and actually be able to adjust/expand it without spending weeks trying to figure the entire thing out.

imagine some1 getting acces to your file and replace all your ';' with the greek questionmark, which looks pretty much identical. Good luck figuring that out if all your code is in 1 file!

Comment: I recommend not to structure modules by type (aka one module for services, one for controllers etc) but by feature (one for pizza iongredients, one for orders, one for waiter shift managment..), so that your modules become reusable, exchangeable and independent

Comment: Well that depends, if you have pieces of code that can indeed be reused and exchanged for lets say a slightly different product of your company, then yes your method is tha best! But if you know in advance that it's a single project with only one purpose, the structure of controllers/directives/services would suffice. If you apply the structure you mentioned (per feature), you could also structure those modules with child-modules for controller/service etc aswell

Comment: In the end I think the most important point here is the point we both make in our answer, to apply some form of structure instead of putting everything in one file!

Comment: Havin **some** kind of structure is definetly the most important point.

Comment: i choose this one because it answered my question  BEFORE going into the obvious design considerations.  With ten developers all working on the oneBigApp.js file the problems with that approach are very clear to me already!

Answer (score 2):

You should just do one thing (one controller, one service, one module) per file and structure your files into an organized folder structure, so that it is easy to find code (and to seperate scopes using [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)s). I recommend to read [a style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) or an [article on the topic](http://cliffmeyers.com/blog/2013/4/21/code-organization-angularjs-javascript).

The total amount of controllers, services etc. that can exist in your application are only limited by your RAM. Performance should not be influenced, as searching for controllers/services to inject is O(n) if not better(its just a simple lookup that happens once per injection/instantiation).

Answer (score 0):

25,000 lines with over 100 controllers/services/directives in a single file can't be good. Consider breaking up your application into various folders (controllers, services, directives, views, etc.) and try and keep as little code per file as possible. Ideally, 1 service/controller per file when in development! How do you even deal with that much code in a single file when developing? You can concat and minify everything with Gulp/Grunt when linking to your index/html file.